# Implement interface in a service and call it in another class -Android

Tags: android, interface, android-service

I have a use case in which I need to update points(markers) on the map when a certain event occurs inside a service. For that am using an interface callback method.

```
    public interface draw 
    {
        void updatePoints(Context context) throws JSONException;
    }
```

Now am using this interface in my Service like this :

```
draw dfc;

...............
//Inside a constructor of a class
dfc=new draw() {
                @Override
                public void updateFloatingPoints(Context context) throws JSONException {
                    System.out.println("Callback in Service");
                    CustomViewView.registerDPCListener(dfc);
                }
            };
```

Now within the same Service, under a certain function, am passing the interface as an input parameter i.e `callback` and inside that function am calling

```
callback.updateFloatingPoints(context);
```

Now when am running the service, I can see the `callback in Service` statement. Till here everything is okay.

Now problem is that, when the callback is received, I want to do some work another class. Let's call it `CustomView`. I implemented the interface in that class too but I am not able to receive the callbacks over there. Follow is the bare bone code of the class

```
public class CustomView extends ABCD implements draw {
    private draw dfcListner=null;
    public void registerDPCListener(drawPath listener) throws JSONException {
        this.dfcListner = listener;
        if(dfcListner!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("Listener initialized");
            //dfcListner.updateFloatingPoints(mcontext);

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Listener is not initialized");
        }
    }
    //Another functions in between over here

    @Override
    public void updateFloatingPoints(Context context) throws JSONException {
        System.out.println("Inside CustomView callback");

    }
}
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: I think you are talking about the observer pattern. You have to register `CustomView` to receive callback updates.

Comment: or if you want to use thirdparty libs like EventBus from green robots.

Comment: Inside the service I did do `CustomViewView.registerDPCListener(dfc);` i.e I assume, that binds the listener of CustomView class to service's listeners. right?

Comment: Post your manifest please